# Css div top and bottom has added void space

Tags: html, css

It has been a few years since I have played around with CSS. Truth be told, I was never that good at it either. I have my code below (or click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJ9ST9I9KFGX)). Basically, there is an added gap/void at the bottom and the top of the red-div (.three).

How do I go about removing this gap? So that the padding/margin/space is 0.

```css
.one {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.two {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.three {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.four {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 3%;
  bottom: 1%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
<div class="four">
</div>
<div class="two">
<div class="three">
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'll add an image so you can see it. Where the blue line is. There should be no space. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xypvY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`.three p:first-child { margin: 0; }`

`.three p:last-child { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

its the p tags inside it that add the space you can remove it with

```
.three:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.three:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child(), Selector for reducing margin in p tag

```css
.one {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.two {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.three {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.four {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 3%;
  bottom: 1%;
  position: absolute;
}
:nth-child(1){
padding-top: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="one">
<div class="four">
</div>
<div class="two">
<div class="three">
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```